# Problem linking Bullet Physics Library (Installed with brew)

Tags: c++, xcode, homebrew, bullet

I'm making a c++ OpenGL game and I tried to add the Bullet library to handle the collision of my game but I'm have trouble installing it. I'm on macOS and I used brew to install Bullet.

It look well installed but when I try to compile anything which include `<bullet/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>` I get this error:

> LinearMath/btVector3.h' file not found (On this line #include "LinearMath/btVector3.h" from brCollisionWorld.h)

Does this problem come with my installation from brew ? Or I'm doing something wrong while linking it ? (I linked the include and the 3 lib to my Xcode project)

Comment: ***I get this error : 'LinearMath/btVector3.h' file not found*** Your first step is to see if this file exists. If it does exist is the folder that contains LinearMath one of the folders in your compilers include path?

Comment: It does exist, but it's at the root of the bullet include folder, so I guess the compiler is looking for the LinearMath folder in the CollisionDispatch folder (witch is the folder where brCollisionWolrd.h is, so not where the CollisionDispatch folder is). But I don't know how to fix this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the appropriate folder to the list of folders your C++ project looks in for header files... though I have no idea how that works in Xcode.  Hopefully someone will have a better answer, but in the mean time this should get you looking in the right direction.

Comment: You'll probably have a similar problem at link time, and will have to add its libraries to your linker's list.  Again, no idea how to do that in Xcode.